# What is the kanji for 'intense game'?

Tags: translation

I believe the romaji is 'hageshi gemu' and I had checked the kanji on Google Translate but it's not 100% trustworthy.

Comment: The word is actually ローマ字, which is *rōmaji*.  There's no 'n' in it.

Comment: Although I understand the question, I am struggling to find which context you are trying to use it in. Although I assume sports (as in 試合), you wouldn't be talking about a videogame would you? In the latter case, it would really depend on what your colloquial meaning for intense is. Intense as in; an encompassing complex experience, a situation that tested your morals, a situation that was non-stop action, a situation where you only got through by the skin of your teeth etc. Just calling something intense in my opinion, opens up a world of misinterpretation. Can you give a bit more context?

Answer (score 2):

Hageshii Ge-mu is 激しいゲーム.  You could also just say [激戦]{げき・せん} or [熱戦]{ねっ・せん}.